# detecting hashtags and @ in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect hashtags and @ and add the class to the world so as I can add a styling.
Right now it is working but I am iteration over text twice.
Can I do it with a one statement?

```
var text = item["text"].replace(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig, "$1<span class='hash_tag'>$2</span>");
    text = text.replace(/(^|\s)(@[a-z\d-]+)/ig, "$1<span class='hash_tag'>$2</span>");
```

Comment: @ is not a hashtag, it's a mention. Perhaps you might want to use different style?

Comment: @MightyPork: OP said "and".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use this in the regex:

```
/(^|\s)([#@][a-z\d-]+)/
```

To match both @ and #.