# How to detect mentions/hashtags when user is typing

Tags: python, mysql, flask, autocomplete, mention

I am trying to create a web app that is similar to Facebook and I was wondering how I can detect mentions/hashtags as the user is typing into an input field? For example, when they write "@jo", I want to create an autocomplete feature that will have the dropdown options of:

```
John Snow
Johnathan Smith
Joey Li
```

This is a web app running on Flask. My database is a MySQL database.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

When the user is typing, you can use Javascript to detect the hashtag with a regEx and then request the database to know if the mention or/and hashtag exists.

RegEx : [detecting hashtags and @ in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083983/detecting-hashtags-and-in-string)

Use of database : [Database design for apps using "hashtags"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799753/database-design-for-apps-using-hashtags#24800716)